# Number of a row consisting of the same set of numbers as another row C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, matrix

OK guys, I have this problem where I have to print the number of the rows of a matrix that are composed from the same set of numbers as the number of a row I input. For example:

---

```
Input:4 5 3
      1 2 2 3
      2 4 1 3
      1 1 1 3
      3 1 1 2
      3 1 3 2
Output:0 4
```

---

Note that we first input the number of the columns,then the rows and then the row k.
I get on the input only the 0 and can't figure why? I think my logic is ok, but who knows I'm new to programing. So if you could tell me where my mistake is that would be great. Here is my code:

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int const l=50;
int main ()
{
int n,m,k,br=0,br2=0;
bool t1=false;
bool t2=false;
cin>>n>>m>>k;
int a[l][l];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        cin>>a[i][j];
}

for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{

for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(a[k][p]==a[i][j])
        {
            br++;
        }
    }
    if(br==0)
    {
        t1=true;
    }
    br=0;
}
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
    {
        if(a[i][j]==a[k][p])
        {
            br2++;
        }
    }
    if(br2==0)
    {
        t2=true;
    }
    br2=0;
}

if(t1==false && t2==false && i!=k)
{
    cout<<i<<" ";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to input a column/row and pull values from a 2d array?

Comment: your code shows that your programming skills are not sufficient to write the algorithm. I would recommend reading more C++ (or any other language) tutorials/docs before jumping into more relatively complex problems.

Comment: @metinoheat In the example I input 3, which is the row {3,1,1,2} and it has the same set of numbers as the 0 row {1,2,2,3} and the 4 row {3,1,3,2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for you. From a high level viewpoint, the basic task is that you want to do a bunch of comparisons between members within an array. I'm not really sure of your code, so here is my own unique solution for you.

step 1 - find all the members of the array row or column that you are interested in, and add them to your list. if you know the sizes of everything than use an array, if not then use a vector. lets call this 1d array memberlist[]

step 2 - loop through memberlist[] and search for each member of memberlist within a every row/column. For this example lets say you are interested in rows, not that there is any real difference.

step 3 - make yet another int array which we will call matchlist[]. matchlist should have a length equal to the number of rows in the array you are comparing with. initialize every value in matchlist to zero.

step 4 - every time you have a hit from the memberlist[] comparing to the rows, add 1 to the corresponding row's score sheet in matchlist.

at the end of the first loop, you should have checked every row for every member of the row you are trying to match it with, and you will get a score for each one contained within matchlist[]. choose the ones with the score you can accept, whether or not thats the full length of memberlist[] or maybe 3 out of 4.

```
int rowsize = 5;
int columnsize = 5;


//step 1
testarray[rowsize][columnsize] = {whatever you want};

//choose row
cin>>row;
int i;
int j;
int memberlist[rowsize] = {0};
for(i = 0; i < rowsize; i++){
memberlist[i] = testarray[i][columnsize]
}
//memberlist is programmed
int tempid;
int membercounter;
int tempmember;

int matchlist[columnsize];
//    step2 & 3
for (membercounter = 0; membercounter < rowsize; membercounter++){
tempmember = memberlist[membercounter];
for(i=0;i<columnsize;i++){
    for (j=0;j<rowsize;j++)
        tempid = temparray[j][i];
//step 4
if ( tempid == tempmember){matchlist[i]++;}
}
}
}

// use some code to cout the columns based on the matchlist score
for (i=0; i< columnsize; i++)
{ printf( "matchlist[%d] has a score of %d \n", i,matchlist[i]);}
//or whatever you want.
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.